# find the new_price for the latest change_date of each product_id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the table:

```
create table products (
product_id int,
new_price int,
change_date date,
primary key (product_id, change_date));

insert into products values
(1, 20, '2019-08-14'),
(2, 50, '2019-08-14'),
(1, 30, '2019-08-15'),
(1, 35, '2019-08-16'),
(2, 65, '2019-08-17'),
(3, 20, '2019-08-18');
```

question: find the new_price for the latest change_date of each product_id
here is my solution:

```
select a.product_id, a.new_price, b.change_date from products a join 
(select product_id, max(change_date) change_date from products 
 group by product_id) b
 on a.product_id = b.product_id and a.change_date = b.change_date;
```

it works as expected:

```
product_id | new_price | change_date
  1             35        2019-08-16
  2             65        2019-08-17
  3             20        2019-08-18
```

is there any more efficient way to solve this? this looks to me a simple question but I have to use a subquery to solve it, so I'm looking to better solution. I use PostgreSQL. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `DISTINCT ON` (postgresql specific feature) and the `LAST_VALUE` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
       product_id,
       LAST_VALUE(new_price) OVER all_rows_by_product_id,
       LAST_VALUE(change_date) OVER all_rows_by_product_id
FROM products
-- named window, you could also simply repeat its definition in both rows above
WINDOW all_rows_by_product_id AS (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY change_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
;
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ product_id │ last_value │ last_value │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│          1 │         35 │ 2019-08-16 │
│          2 │         65 │ 2019-08-17 │
│          3 │         20 │ 2019-08-18 │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

---

Note: in this case `SELECT DISTINCT` would also work, as all rows for a `product_id` would be identical. This would make this query not postgresql-specific.
However the `DISTINCT ON (product_id)` is closer to what you want to express, plus it will still return what you want even if you add some other column.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the main ways a problem like that is solved though it comes with the caveat that if there are two new prices on the same day it will return both

An alternative is to use row number:

```
select x.product_id, x.new_price, x.change_date from
(
  select p.product_id, p.new_price, p.change_date, row_number() over(partition by p.product_id order by p.change_date desc) rn
  from products p
) x
where x.rn=1
```

Analytic functions are a bit like an inline grouping operation - the result set is partitioned (grouped) on product id and rows are numbered in descending order of date. Every partition has a row number 1, which is the most recent date. The outer where clause selects only those rows with rn=1, being the latest rows

This will only return one price if there are two on a day but it's unknown which one you'll get. To make sure, add another rule to the order by, like adding in price (always gives the higher price) or some other column. You could also increase the granularity of the date to include a time too

In terms of performance, this method only requires one scan of the table data rather than two, though various db may have specific optimizations for the oft used pattern of "get the latest row". Which would be faster or cheaper in your case would be something to test